# How to create internal and external links

Tags: nodes

In drupal 4.x, in contents, links are created like this
[url=1]Some text[/url]
So when "Some text" click it open node 1.

Sometime it may link to external url also. like below:
[url=http://www.abc.com/somepage.html] external link [/url]

same thing how can i do it in drupal 7.x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be honest, I don't know anything about Drupal 4.  I don't regard it as a platform to build on in 2014.

In Drupal 7, out of he box, you create links using plain HTML:

```
<a href="/node/42" title="internal link">internal link</a>
<a href="http://example.com/somepage.html" title="external link">external link</a>
```

There are a bunch of modules for Drupal 7 you can install that gives you other syntaxes for adding links to content. To mimic the square brackets around tags syntax you cite as example. Install the [Bbcode](https://drupal.org/project/bbcode) module.  It uses markup based upon [BBCode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode).  For a more modern style, similar to StackExchange, install the [Markdown filter](https://drupal.org/project/markdown) module. It let content authors use markup based upon [John Gruber's Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, then you need way to differentiate internal URL with External URL and there is way out.

If you want to give internal link just give like 'node/' in href where if you want to connect link with external URL, give full URL like 'http://www.google.com'.

Now, if you have question how drupal will recognize it, we have module extlink (https://drupal.org/project/extlink) which does that job.

hope this answers give you what you seeking for.